# How can I change the directory of weblogic installation?

Tags: linux, oracle, directory, weblogic, middleware

I have the Oracle Weblogic binaries installed in a particular location on linux servers. For example, -
**/oracle/middleware1211/**

I also have the 'user_projects/domains' installed in the same directory. For example, -
**/oracle/middleware1211/user_projects**

My question is , how do I reconfigure/move the "user_projects" or "domains" directory out of the current directory ? For example, location should be, -
**/oracle/user_projects**

Not planning to rename the domains , just move the directories so we have a same directory structure across all weblogic environments.

We are in the process of consolidation of all our Weblogic environments, and one of the steps is getting the domains moved outside the main Weblogic binary installation.

Thank you for your replies in advance.

I have tried using , **reconfig.sh ,** to change the installation directory, but could not get it to work as I wanted to. Hoping there are some other alternatives or methods I can look into.

Answer (score 1):

You can move a Weblogic Domain, changing the **DOMAIN_HOME** in the domain scripts.

If you check all the scripts in the path **/oracle/middleware1211/user_projects/*domain_name*/bin**, you have this variable, with the current domain path, in some of them.

You have to copy all the domain directory to the new location, the best way is with rsync command and the domain stopped. You can sincronice the first time with the domain started, but i recomend you to do a last sincronization when you stop the domain, before the domain path changes.

After that, you have to change all the **DOMAIN_HOME** variables in all the scripts located in the new location (**/*new_domains_location*/*domain_name*/bin/**), with the new domain path and starts the domain.

Starts first the admin server in the new location, and check in the log files that all is correct, then starts the managed servers.

If you have any problem and does not works, you can starts the domain in the old location, that is unchanged and have to works.

Obviously, you could make a first attempt in a test domain (or a new installed domain), to verify that the process is correct. Then you have to do the same steps with the rest of the domains.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hello Miner Willy,
Thank you for your reply.
This looks like a good solution , and something I can tinkle around with to see if it works as expected. Of course , I will first start testing in an QA environment to see if the method works. 
I am not familiar with the rsync commands based for weblogic to sync all changes made to the domain. Looking at your reply, it came to my mind that maybe I could also use the "pack.sh" and "unpack.sh" script to unpack the domain in the new location. This will of course have the changes I made to the DOMAIN_HOME in it.
Is this a good alternative as well?

Comment: The pack.sh is a new script in Weblogic 12, I did not use it for this. Maybe is a good choice, this script packs only the necesary files and directories of the domain. Appearily is more clean than copy all the files.

Comment: Anyway if you want to try with rsync, it is easy, with a single command line you can sincronice the domain directory to the new ubication:

`rsync -avz --delete /old/domains/location/domain_name /new_domains_location`

Notice that there is not slashs at the end of the both parameters and the destination do not have the name of the domain. It is not necesary create the domain directory in the /new_domains_location, rsync synchronizes and create the domain_name directory.

Comment: After the first sincronization, you can run the same command and the next time the time will be much less, because only synchronizes the changes respect the previous sincronization.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the 'rsync' process. I will give both methods a try and see which ones works well. I will post my findings when all my testing has been done.